# Missing lxml module in python?

Tags: python, ironpython, lxml, python-import

I want o use `Python-docx` library to process word files.  A `docx.py` references lxml, as i assume from

```
from lxml import etree
```

When i start the script, i get error:

```
No module named lxml
```

Is this a standard library? Why is not it referenced properly then? IronPython 2.7 RC1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install [lxml](http://lxml.de/) which is not part of the stdlib.  I don't know if it will work with IronPython though.

*Update*: Seems like it might be non-trivial to get lxml working with IronPython.  See this question:

- [How to get lxml working under IronPython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200726/how-to-get-lxml-working-under-ironpython)

Comment: thanks. it's very disappointing that cpython can do something ironpython can't ;(

Comment: cpython can load extension modules written to CPython's internal C-API.