# Simplest way to expose my python program to .Net/C# - can't use ironpython

Tags: c#, .net, python, web-services

I have a custom business logic written in python - there are various reasons I can't write it directly in C#/.Net (time constraints etc.).

I tried integrating the python program into .Net using IronPython but cannot ([lxml being one of the reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202368/missing-lxml-module-in-python)).

> I'm turning to the simpler solution of exposing this python logic as a
>   web service which .Net can call.

-

> First I thought I'd have to host my python code on a separate domain..
>   But I realized, I can install python on the same server & run this python service !!

The functionality is simple -
.Net passes a URL & the python program returns data as a long string.

**1**.) What would be the simplest way to do this ?
**2**.) Do I need to use a framework like web2py/werkzeug or is there something built in I can use ?!

Comment: Please tell, have you considered option of starting Python part from command line with .NET part of the application (and re-directing output)? It seems to be simpler than implementation of web services.

Comment: Have you checked out django? it's mvc in python. You can just write a view to achieve what you wanted: accept request, return data.

Comment: @AndriiKalytiiuk - hmmm... I thought about that but how do I get the data returned from the python program ? Storing result of each function-call in a file would be cumbersome..

Comment: @goldenparrot - thanks, yes have used dJango, but that'd be too heavy for this.

Comment: What Andrii said... just use pipes. I'm using them to communicate between JS and Python right now quite successfully.

Comment: AndriiKalytiiuk & @Mark - I did try invoking the python script directly & I think I can make the output files work. I used the regular Process.start(). What are you referring to when you say "pipes" ?

Comment: @PlanetUnknown: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_pipe I just mean communicating over stdin/stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would give [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/) a try. I have been using it in the past, and it was extremely easy to learn.

Anyway, I think I would suggest you to prepare a small webservice running locally (using Tornado). This webservice could be then easily accessed by any code running on the same machine, and if there is a need - from another machine as well.

Oh, and Tornado is much lighter than Django...

(The sample code below is a Hello-World sample from Tornado website - I've just copied it here to show how easy it is to use Tornado):

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # put your calculation logic in here (instead of "Hello World"
        self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

One of the great advantages of Tornado is that it is simple to do simple task but just in case you need something more sophisticated - it is easy to use them.

Oh, and another thing to bear in mind - I don't know what your code is actually doing but I think it could be a good idea to consider designing your webservice' API with REST in mind.

Comment: I like what I see here.. ! If invoking the python using Process.start  does pose any issues I will definitely try this.

Comment: Please note, that using web-services seems to be more flexible, and starting python as a process has 2 drawbacks: 1) it will not perform that well, as python has to be started each time you want to get the result; it will not be possible to cache results as well. 2) it will be easier to replace each part (client or server) when the REST API is defined and working.
It may seem to be more complicated than using Process.Start, but it is not tighly coupled.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered publishing your python code as a com object ? I have done this in the past.

See the section "Implementing COM Objects in Python" in http://oreilly.com/catalog/pythonwin32/chapter/ch12.html

Not sure how it fits with you .Net environment but it is doable.

Other I would investigate just wrapping it in a simple XMLRPC service if it's only used in you local environment, that way you do have to go into framework territory (like Django etc).

Comment: Thanks Tim, but compiling doesn't look possible especially given the issues I had creating a dll from lxml.

Comment: There is no need to compile anything.  Did you see the chapter I referred to, this is normal python, with some addition python code registering the com interface.